# How is Melatonin Synthesised?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, synthesis, chemical-biology

I should like to know roughly how the hormone melotonin is *synthetically* made for the pharmaceutical industry (i.e. not how it is made in living beings). I can't seem to find any reference to its manufacture on the web, it is seen to have a fairly simple structure on its Wiki page and biologically it is synthesised from the forerunner amino acid tryptophan. So I believe it is likely to be readily synthesised for use in pharmaceuticals without the use of animal products, but I cannot confirm this.

Specifically, a close relative of mine has been prescribed melotonin and I want to confirm that this substance is not made from animal products, as I live in a country where the authorities in their great wisdom have deregulated the food and meat processing industries. Astoundingly, they did this at exactly the same time that a UK royal commission recommended *re-regulation of the same* to prevent contamination of food and pharmaceuticals by the Creutzfeld-Jacob prion.

Comment: I don't wish to be argumentative, but even if someone can provide details of a fully synthetic industrial production route, what guarantee does that provide that the manufacturer you're specifically dealing with uses that route?

Comment: @GregE. None, just gathering evidence to get me one step from a state of complete to partial ignorance: an answer of how it is generally done changes conditional probabilities

Comment: Fair enough. You may find these useful: [1](http://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/local/projects/s_thipayang/synth.html), [2](http://www.ema.europa.eu/docs/en_GB/document_library/EPAR_-_Scientific_Discussion/human/000695/WC500026808.pdf). The first is an overview of some synthetic strategies, the second is an EMA report on Circadin (a sustained-release melatonin formulation) which describes a synthesis starting from 5-methoxytryptamine. To my (admittedly limited) knowledge, amino acids (and relatives) are rarely produced by extraction methods these days, but rather by enzymatic and semi-synthetic routes.

Comment: There's also [another document](http://www.tga.gov.au/pdf/auspar/auspar-circadin.pdf) pertaining to Circadin, this one from the Australian Dept. of Health, describing the same synthetic method. If you do a search on tryptamine production, you'll find bacterial and enzymatic routes described, which (to my knowledge) is in line with trends for production of these sorts of compounds. I haven't found a source describing the production of the 5-methoxy derivative specifically, but the synthesis from tryptamine would be a simple one, and I find it unlikely that extraction methods would be used.

Comment: @GregE. I think whenever you like, you might post an answer to this....

Comment: First, if it is a supplement from some natural product store, it is most probably not made by a chemist, and probably not even subjected to quality control and might not even contain melatonin. Second, if it is a prescribed it is made according to the Good Manufacturing Practice mandatory for all prescription drugs, the source will be indistinguishable and thus the effect. Third, since synthetic drugs are always made from an advanced intermediate found in nature or refined petroleum products which might be some dead dinosaurs there is a strong probability that it will be made from an animal.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the exact process in industry, but these are the steps that I thought of (someone likely thought of this before me, it is a very simple synthesis).  The main synthesis of the ring is done in Fischer indole conditions.  Therefore I broke up the molecule into a compound known as 4-acetamidobutanal and p-hydrazinoanisole.  The first compound is an amide that is available from the reaction of 4-aminobutanal and acetyl chloride or acetic anhydride in the presence of a base.  The latter compound is available from the reaction of p-anisidine with sodium nitrite and hydrochloric acid to form the diazonium chloride, and then reduction with sodium sulfite and sodium hydroxide.  This is just an example of a synthesis.  The overall synthesis shouldn't be more than 5 or 6 steps.

I found an [article](https://www.thevespiary.org/rhodium/Rhodium/pdf/novel.melatonin.syntheses.pdf) highlighting the syntheses, you can take a look.  Apparently the synthesis that I described above is very similar to the most effective synthesis, a one-pot synthesis done in very similar conditions and having similar starting materials.